# EnvInject plugin not copying the variables

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have installed the EnvInject plugin in Jenkins and trying to add the variables in a job, which is run on a windows slave
The build step is as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGFGd.jpg)

When the job is run, this build step is successful with below steps

[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.

[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'mw/proj/MW_ver.txt'

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.

The contents of the ver.txt is ***VERSION = 4.6***

When de-referencing, I expect 4.6, but I am seeing ${VERSION} as output

Is the way I de-reference is wrong?

Comment: can you show the script that is de-referencing it (something that includes ${VERSION})? are you using single quotes instead of double quotes by chance?

Comment: I added a build step execute windows batch command. In that im trying to rename a folder  with command:   rename newfolder ${VERSION}

Comment: i don't think this is the issue, but the contexts of ver.txt should probably be `VERSION=4.6` (no spaces).

Comment: finally I got the answer. I had to use "execute shell" instead of "execute windows batch command". Because this de-referencing is happening in shell window only.